# Matching CLI Bootstrap Params to pub/index.php's Bootstrap Params

Tags: magento2, cli, index.php

Magento 2 has, infamously, two `index.php` files.  The first is in the root folder

```
index.php
```

the second is in a `pub` folder

```
pub/index.php
```

A Magento developer needs to chose which file they're going to point to as their webroot.  This creates some problems related to file paths and URL paths.  Magento solves this by bootstrapping index.php like this

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
```

and bootstrapping `pub/index.php` like this

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

i.e. -- Magento adds values to the array that's the second argument to `create`.

This solution, however, creates another problem.  The [Magento CLI also need to bootstrap an enviornment](https://twitter.com/fschmengler/status/811827744359194624).  It seems to do so here

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php
$bootstrapParam = new ComplexParameter(self::INPUT_KEY_BOOTSTRAP);
$params = $bootstrapParam->mergeFromArgv($_SERVER, $_SERVER);
$params[Bootstrap::PARAM_REQUIRE_MAINTENANCE] = null;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

There's (Seemingly?) no opportunity to add additional parameters, which means the CLI console will always think you're running from the main index file, and any code that needs the `DirectoryList` params may not function correctly.

Is there any way (short of editing `Cli.php`  directly or replacing it via a composer autoload) to inject these parameters into the CLI bootstrap?  Looking for known solutions, not theories on what might work.  Thank you!

Comment: since you do not look for theories and also might have already tried this, I#ll just leave a comment. You might be able to manipulate the $_SERVER array (not sure if that works) with a compose autoload file (same way as registration.php). I really think there is no "nice" solution except magento just removing the {root}/index.php file